# ImageMagick convert tiffs to pdf with sequential file suffix

Tags: bash, pdf, imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I have the following scenario and I'm not much of a coder (nor do I know bash well). I don't even have a base working bash script to share, so any help would be appreciated.

I have a file share that contains tiffs (thousands) of a document management system. The goal is to convert and combine from multiple file tiffs to single file pdfs (preferably PDF/A 1a format).

The directory format:

```
/Document Management Root     # This is root directory
 ./2009/                      # each subdirectory represents a year
 ./2010/
 ./2011/
 ....
 ./2016/
 ./2016/000009.001            
 ./2016/000010.001
              # files are stored flat - just thousands of files per year directory
```

The document management system stores tiffs with sequential number file names along with sequential file suffixes:

```
000009.001
000010.001
000011.002
000012.003
000013.001
```

Where each page of a document is represented by the suffix. The suffix restarts when a new, non-related document is created. In the example above, `000009.001` is a single page tiff. Files `000010.001`, `000011.002`, and `000012.003` belong to the same document (i.e. the pages are all related). File `000013.001` represents a new document.

I need to preserve the file name for the first file of a multipage document so that the filename can be cross referenced with the document management system database for metadata.

The pseudo code I've come up with is:

```
for each file in {tiff directory}
    while file extension is "001"
      convert file to pdf and place new pdf file in {pdf directory}
    else 
      convert multiple files to pdf and place new pd file in {pdf  directory}
```

But this seems like it will have the side effect of converting all 001 files regardless of what the next file is.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT - Both answers below work. The second answer worked, however it was my mistake in not realizing that the data set I tested against was different than my scenario above.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, save the following script in your login ($HOME) directory as `TIFF2PDF`

```
#!/bin/bash
ls *[0-9] | awk -F'.' '
   /001$/ { if(NR>1)print cmd,outfile; outfile=$1 ".pdf"; cmd="convert " $0;next}
          { cmd=cmd " " $0}
   END    { print cmd,outfile}'
```

and make it executable (necessary just once) by going in Terminal and running:

```
chmod +x TIFF2PDF
```

Then copy a few documents from any given year into a temporary directory to try things out... then go to the directory and run:

```
~/TIFF2PDF
```

**Sample Output**

```
convert 000009.001 000009.pdf
convert 000010.001 000011.002 000012.003 000010.pdf
convert 000013.001 000013.pdf
```

If that looks correct, you can actually execute those commands like this:

```
~/TIFF2PDF | bash
```

or, preferably if you have **GNU Parallel** installed:

```
~/TIFF2PDF | parallel
```

The script says... *"Generate a listing of all files whose names end in a digit and send that list to `awk`. In `awk`, use the dot as the separator between fields, so if the file is called `00011.0002`, then `$0` will be `00011.0002`, `$1` will be `00011` and `$2` will be `0002`. Now, if the filename ends in `0001`, print the accumulated command and append the output filename. Then save the filename prefix with `PDF` extension as the output filename of the next PDF and start building up the next **ImageMagick** `convert` command. On subsequent lines (which don't end in `0001`), add the filename to the list of filenames to include in the `PDF`. At the end, output any accumulated commands and append the output filename."*

---

As regards the ugly black block at the bottom of your image, it happens because there are some tiny white specks in there that prevent ImageMagick from removing the black area. I have circled them in red:

[image]

If you blur the picture a little (to diffuse the specks) and then get the size of the trim-box, you can apply that to the original, unblurred image like this:

```
trimbox=$(convert original.tif -blur x2 -bordercolor black -border 1 -fuzz 50% -format %@ info:)
convert original.tif -crop $trimbox result.tif
```

[image]

I would recommend you do that first to A COPY of all your images, then run the PDF conversion afterwards. As you will want to save a TIFF file but with the extension `0001`, `0002`, you will need to tell **ImageMagick** to trim and force the output filetype to TIF:

```
original=XYZ.001
trimbox=$(convert $original -blur x2 -bordercolor black -border 1 -fuzz 50% -format %@ info:)
convert $original -crop $trimbox TIF:$original
```

---

As @AlexP. mentions, there can be issues with globbing if there is a large number of files. On OSX, ARG_MAX is very high (262144) and your filenames are around 10 characters, so you may hit problems if there are more than around 26,000 files in one directory. If that is the case, simply change:

```
ls *[0-9] | awk ...
```

to

```
ls | grep "\d$" | awk ...
```

Comment: This successfully produces output that matches your sample output.

Comment: That seems to have done it, but there's a black border across the bottom that I am unable to get rid of. I modified the cmd='convert ' section as follows:      `cmd="convert " $0 " -fuzz 1% -trim +repage ";next}`.  This doesn't seem to make a difference.  I sanitized one of the documents created (the green border represents the redacted overlay): https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxhnrfro69zwzez/00000023.pdf?dl=0

Comment: That's a different problem - this question is about combining sequentially numbered documents into a single PDF. Can I suggest you ask a new question, providing one of your skewed scans (presumably?) - preferably with at least some sample text and asking how to get rid of the black?

Comment: got it. I'll mark your response as the Answer. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, there are couple of potential issues with your solution. The worst one is using *globbing* in the `ls` command in a folder with potentially thousands of files.

Comment: @AlexP. Thank you for your thoughts. Globbing can be readily fixed if it is an issue - what were the others please?

Comment: I just do not like relying on `ls` output in general. I frequently see it *aliased* to some obscure sorting defaults for example. I do not like wasting more time down the road trying to figure out why my old script which used to work before suddenly stopped working (after being copied to another  system for example).

Comment: I agree that the image processing part deserves its own separate question. Also that way @MarkSetchell gets twice the credit

Answer (score 1):

The following command would convert the whole `/Document Management Root` tree (assuming it's actual absolute path) properly processing all subfolders even with names including whitespace characters and properly skipping all other files not matching the `000000.000` naming pattern:

```
find '/Document Management Root' -type f -regextype sed -regex '.*/[0-9]\{6\}.001$' -exec bash -c 'p="{}"; d="${p:0: -10}"; n=${p: -10:6}; m=10#$n; c[1]="$d$n.001"; for i in {2..999}; do k=$((m+i-1)); l=$(printf "%s%06d.%03d" "$d" $k $i); [[ -f "$l" ]] || break; c[$i]="$l"; done; echo -n "convert"; printf " %q" "${c[@]}" "$d$n.pdf"; echo' \; | bash
```

To do a dry run just remove the `| bash` in the end.

Updated to match the `00000000.000` pattern (and split to multiple lines for clarity):

```
find '/Document Management Root' -type f -regextype sed -regex '.*/[0-9]\{8\}.001$' -exec bash -c '
  pages[1]="{}"
  p1num="10#${pages[1]: -12:8}"
  for i in {2..999}; do
    nextpage=$(printf "%s%08d.%03d" "${pages[1]:0: -12}" $((p1num+i-1)) $i)
    [[ -f "$nextpage" ]] || break
    pages[i]="$nextpage"
  done
  echo -n "convert"
  printf " %q" "${pages[@]}" "${pages[1]:0: -3}pdf"
  echo
' \; | bash
```

Comment: This only returns a prompt and does not make any changes to the files in the Document Management Root directory.

Comment: have you tried with the `echo` instead of `convert`? also do `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: Tried 'echo' instead of 'convert' and it returned a prompt.

Comment: echo $BASH_VERSION displays 4.3.46(1)-release.

Comment: your `bash` is recent enough for the `-exec` part not to be an issue. so run the `find` without the `-exec` part to see if it finds anything

Comment: if I exclude `-exec` it returns: `find: paths must precede expression: bash
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec|time] [path...] [expression]`

Comment: sorry. my answer was meant for someone capable to properly run a basic `find` command. if you are interested to make my answer work for you I suggest you ask for help with the `find` command you tried to run at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The data set I was trying against had 8 characters in the filename, e.g. `00000001.001` so the regex was failing. Once I changed the regex to `\{8\}.001$' it worked.